# Is there a way to defer persisting has_many :through associations until the main object is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have an model that needs to verify accessibility based on a `has_many :through` association before I want to save the model. Something like this:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :category_documents
  has_many :categories, through: :category_documents

  validate :categories_are_accessible_to_organization

  private
    def categories_are_accessible_to_organization
      if (organization.category_ids & category_ids) != category_ids
        errors.add(:categories, "not accessible to the parent organization")
      end
    end
end
```

On new records there doesn't seem to be a problem. However, for persisted records, if the validation fails the categories added during the update will persist. Is there a way to defer the persistence of these join models until the `Document` object passes validation and is saved through any built-in mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

For checking validation of associations, you can used `validates_associated :categories`, read about that from [link-1](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated), [link-2](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated).

For checking validation of `Document`, you do that in `documents_controller.rb` in update action as the following:

```
def update
  @document.attributes = document_params

  respond_to do |format|
    if @document.valid? && @document.update(document_params)
      format.html { redirect_to documents_path, notice: 'Document was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    end
  end
end
```

My idea that you used [attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes) for active-record to check on validation before than save any associated object.

Comment: The problem is not whether the associated objects are valid. It's whether the associations set are valid to be associated given another association. I did try putting `validates_associated` on the join model, but it just raises an error no matter the state. The problem is that assignment of associated HMT is immediate upon assignment for persisted objects, whether using `#attributes=` or `#update`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same goal by moving the validation to join model (i.e. `CategoryDocument`), something like this

```
class CategoryDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
   belongs_to :document

   before_save do
     false unless document.organization.category_ids.include?(category.id)
   end
end
```

This will make operations like this fail

```
Document.first.categories << category_that_does_not_satisfy_validation # raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
```

Comment: This is pretty close to adding `validates_associated` on the join model. The problem here is that it still attempts to create them immediately, which causes an error to be raised and the rest of the assignments to fail. The validation won't pass even if the rest of the parameters would have allowed it to, since the error is raised immediately. I need to completely defer saving/validating of the association until the owner is validated and saved. Where would be the proper place to rescue the error raised?

Comment: The controller would be my choice to rescue from the error. That aside, I can't find a way to defer persistence without doing some ugly meta-programming, sorry :(.